# background-size contain AND length

Tags: css, background-image

I have a div that has a background image with the size set to contain. However, the image is a double resolution image for retina computers (Macbook Pro, etc), so I'd like to be able to make the page aware somehow that even though I'm saying background-size:contain with a 200x200 image, it should be treating it as if its a 100x100 image. Is there any way to do this? Essentially I *want* something like this:

```
{
    background-position:center bottom;
    background-size:contain
    background-size-again:100px 100px; /*???*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you should use

```
background-size:cover
```

This will then force the image to stay at a high resolution and then set the element size to the size you want it, for example 100px x 100px

Comment: I am already using background-size to say "contain", this is my issue.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem?

Comment: If you have a div that has background-size set to contain, you can no longer make it aware of the size the image should be, since you can't say "background-size:contain 100px 100px;" You can EITHER say "background-size:contain" or "background-size:100px 100px;"

Comment: Okay in that case you should make the element in which the background sits 100px heigh and 100px wide, this will then make the image contain that element at that size

Comment: But that does something different. It forces the image to always be 100 high, which is not the behavior of contain. If I simply replace the 2x image with a 1x image, the page behaves the way I want it to (with the image being scaled up and down through contain), but it just looks fuzzy since its not a retina image. I want this same behavior, just with a 2x image. If I set it to a static 100px, it will no longer scale up. I will make a test case momentarily to illustrate the problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: I now see your problem! - Check out my edited answer

Comment: Basically you should use background-size:cover instead of contain. Then set the element to 100px heigh and 100px wide

Comment: This is how I create my backgrounds for my webapps for hd display, I create a container at 1024px x 768px (for ipad) then use a background image of 4x that size and just use cover which compresses it down to the correct size while keeping the correct resolution and DPI! - I hope that helps!